# Build / Deployment process for .Net/Mulesoft/Oracle stack

Tags: continuous-integration, deployment, continuous-deployment, java, dotnet

I have the following challenge to streamline and setup a development process.

The program runs simultaneously, and each one has its own timeline for release, as follows:

- Program 1
- Program 2
- Program 3
- Program 4
- Program 5

Under each of the programmes, there are multiple projects running in parallel. Each project has a different technology, like Web layer `(.NET)`, middle-ware `(Mulesoft)` or database `(Oracle)`.

The challenge is that I have to find a configuration management tool, which considers branching, automated build process, deployment and integration tracking with JIRA.

Can some one suggest the best tool to seamlessly integrate and orchestrate automated build and deployments?

Technologies involved are:

- Oracle (Basically SQL scripts)
- Middleware (Mulesoft - maven script)
- .NET web layer (UI part)

Key points to be considered is the build and deployment process should be technology agnostic, as I have an environment with `java`, `.NET` and `oracle world`.

I am thinking of ( Github - Bitbucket/Bitbucket pipeline) actually but any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please review the edit I just made to ensure I did kept in lin with your question.

Comment: The title on this question is too generic.

Answer (score 3):

For something that requires being agnostic to the tooling, and having the flexibility you need, your best bet is Jenkins.  https://jenkins.io/.  They have a ton of plugins that would meet any use case.  Be aware that Jenkins can be heavy for small teams, but your other options lack the flexibility and support for different communities.

You can check out other tools:

- Team city
- CircleCI/Travis CI
- Semaphore
- ETC